# How to get the indexes of the greatest N values greater than a threshold in Numpy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

For a project I need to be able to get, from a vector with shape `(k, m)`, the indexes of the N greatest values of each row greater than a fixed threshold.
For example, if k=3, m=5, N=3 and the threshold is 5 and the vector is :

```py
[[3 2 6 7 0],
[4 1 6 4 0],
[7 10 6 9 8]]
```

I should get the result (or the flattened version, I don't care) :

```py
[[2, 3],
[2],
[1, 3, 4]]
```

The indexes don't have to be sorted.

My code is currently :

```py
indexes = []
for row, inds in enumerate(np.argsort(results, axis=1)[:, -N:]):
    for index in inds:
        if results[row, index] > threshold:
            indexes.append(index)
```

but I feel like I am not using Numpy to its full capacity.

Does anybody know a better and more elegant solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this method:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array(
    [[3, 2, 6, 7, 0],
     [4, 1, 6, 4, 0],
     [7, 10, 6, 9, 8]]
)
t = 5
n = 3

sorted_idxs = arr.argsort(1)[:, -n:]
sorted_arr  = np.sort(arr, 1)[:, -n:]
item_nums   = np.cumsum((sorted_arr > t).sum(1))
masked_idxs = sorted_idxs[sorted_arr > t]
idx_lists   = np.split(masked_idxs, item_nums)
```

output:

```
[array([2, 3]), array([2]), array([4, 3, 1])]
```